# FIFO queue - tf.string shape

Tags: tensorflow

I have a FIFO queue which takes a (image, label and string) tuple as follows;

```
imageQ = tf.FIFOQueue(128,[tf.uint8,tf.float32,tf.string])
```

I want to dequeue many i.e. in batch but need to specify shapes but I am not sure what shape to specify for the string object. For example;

```
imageQ = tf.FIFOQueue(128,[tf.uint8,tf.float32,tf.string], shapes = [[600,800,3],[1],[?]])
```

How to I shape the string tensor into the queue?

Answer (score 1):

Just realised I just had to reshape the string;

```
str = tf.reshape(str,[1])
imageQ = tf.FIFOQueue(128,[tf.uint8,tf.float32,tf.string], shapes = [[600,800,3],[1],[1]])
```